# version mismatch between the TensorFlow library and the NumPy library

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have installed all modules and dependencies but still i cant access the tensorflow and the error pops as below:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Check for TensorFlow GPU access

print(f"TensorFlow has access to the following devices:\n{tf.config.list_physical_devices()}")

## See TensorFlow version

print(f"TensorFlow version: {tf.**version**}")

---

```
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)RuntimeError: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

```
File ~/miniforge3/envs/env_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/pywrap_tf_session.py:19
     17 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
     18 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
---> 19 from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import *
     20 from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import _TF_SetTarget
     21 from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import _TF_SetConfig

ImportError: initialization failed
```

Answer (score 1):

we can resolve this issue by running this command in the terminal which installs the compatible numpy and tensorflow versions :

```
pip install -U --user pip numpy wheel packaging requests opt_einsum
pip install -U --user keras_preprocessing --no-deps
```